# Is there anything I can try that might get a lost file on Windows 10 back?

Tags: windows

On Windows 10, a text file of mine disappeared. I don't know how it could have happened -- makes no sense. I've checked the recycle bin. I know some of its contents and have tried using findstr to search for it using that, but no luck so far.

I have a 2-week-old backup, but it's obviously missing stuff I added to it after that.

My guess is that the file is unrecoverable. Is there anything I can try that might
get it back?

Answer (score 1):

First advice is not to use the disk at all.
The file's data might still exist on the disk, and the
file's entry in the disk's metadata might still partially exist
and help in recovering the file.
Writing on the disk might damage this data and make its recovery impossible.

You will need to use a data-recovery product to find the deleted file.

One product I have used in the past and can recommend is
[MiniTool Data Recovery Software Free](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery-software/free-for-windows.html).

Let MiniTool scan the disk and search for deleted files. If it finds
the file by name (the first character might be mangled), then you
might have found your data.
Otherwise, it might find the file but not its name,
but it will probably indicate the right folder for it.

Also note that such products may find several old versions of your
file, so check well the data of any file that is found.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. (Is there a way to get an email notification when someone answers one of my questions?)

Comment: @dan profile > settings > edit email settings > inbox

Comment: Thanks re email settings.

Comment: If file is (was) on c: drive you can not download/install file recovery tools on that same drive. You should also consider that Windows writes to c: and so there's a substantial risk of the file content being overwritten.

Comment: Thanks again for the MiniTool suggestion. Unfortunately, no soap.

Comment: MiniTool gave me the best results when I had a corrupted disk. If it has failed, it's possible that the file is lost.